# When declining 401k coverage is it necessary to disclose my Social Security Number (SSN)?

Tags: human-resources, compensation, privacy

To be clear the employer already has employees' SSN, but in declining a new enrollment with 401k benefit, which requests (among other things) an SSN.  Is one in any way obligated to give them this info?  Is the employer allowed to?  Would they (The 401k supplier) have any good reason for it?

Edit:  This not stopping a current deduction.  This is an initial enrollment.  Also this is not about my company specifically but any employer in the US which does not qualify as a small business.  Nor is it about a specific 401k provider, but about any new 401k program starting at such a company.

Comment: You could contact the plan administrator for your employer and just ask them.

Comment: That is of course very reasonable, however, I do not want to take their word for it.  The office personnel here would tend to respond with something like "Well if they ask for it they need it" or "I need it because they asked", and I am not inclined to ask them only to then argue with them.

Comment: If you never fill in the form to enroll in the 401k, how can the 401k supplier get your SSN?

Comment: You have to fill in the form to decline it as well.  I simply left the SSN field blank.

Comment: I think your HR plan administrator will need to report that you declined 401K participation unless the benefit provider firm does it. I am pretty sure government at some point is tallying that information and since you are your SSN to the government, they will need it for statistical purposes. Your HR benefits administrator is trying to make life easy for himself/herself I think.

Comment: **Note to would-be answerers:** while this is borderline off-topic, people with HR experience or experience in dealing with these kinds of companies and benefits should be able to give a general answer without having to interpret the OP's specific situation. While that makes this on-topic, please refrain from posting useless answers like "*They shouldn't in my opinion because....*" or "*I don't really know but I guess...*".

Comment: For us lesser mortals - please tell me what is 401k benefit

Comment: @EdHeal in the US a 401k is a retirement account where the taxes are deferred until you withdraw and, often, the company will match some level of contribution into the account.  The account will often let you select from a number of investment plans.

Comment: @EricRenouf - You mean a pension plan

Comment: @EdHeal 401k's are what replaced pension plans, since pension plans have the company paying much much more generally.  So this is related to, but a bit different from a pension plan (at least in the US)

Comment: 401k's (named after the section of the law that created them) have sometimes been referred to as "a self-directed defined-contribution portable pension". That isn't exact, but it does c capture the differences between this and traditional pensions; companies have offloaded much of the risk and responsibility to the employees.

Comment: @MelBurslan the IRS Already gets that reported to them annually from the employer.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you work for a company that has setup their 401K retirement program with automatic enrollment. To stop the process from starting or to end the automatic deductions they need you to fill out a form.

Many companies refer to you either by employee number or by social security number. Your employer does have social security number due to their payroll requirements.

The company running the 401k generally needs a taxid number for every account. This goes for IRA accounts, 401k accounts and non-retirement accounts.

Your name on the form is not good enough, the company running the 401K may need to be able to document your declining. They may even have to refund your initial contributions in some cases. Your employer  and their payroll processor needs to turn off the deduction. Your employer may need to prove to the feds that every employee was initially enrolled in the retirement program but some declined.

Keep in mind that HR can just add your SSN and pass it to the 401K company. If your work for a small company your name alone may be enough for HR to 100% identify you. For a large company they will need your employee ID number. Of course it might delay the stopping for a paycheck or two.